# Uploading Google indoor map? & How can I check and view it?

Tags: android, google-maps, gis

I am trying to create an android navigation system app for my University Campus as a project of one of my courses. I searched a lot for different solutions to implement my project. "Google indoor map" solution attracted my attention.

- First, I prepared my University's map with appropriate quality.
- Second, I followed the steps that were mentioned on [this
  website](http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1685896&topic=1685871&ctx=topic).
- Third, I uploaded my indoor map [here](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/floorplans/).
- Fourth, I submitted my work and it was mentioned that it will be
  reviewed by Google to be accepted (I submitted it maybe from 3 days).

Now, how can I know that my map was accepted? How can I view it? I really need it.

I noticed an important comment that was written [here](http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1685896&topic=1685871&ctx=topic). This is the **comment**:

> "Note: This option is only available in the US, UK, and Japan. Also,
>   you can only upload a floor plan from your computer."

**WHY?!**
Is this true?!!! Then, does this mean that I will not be able to view my uploaded indoor map of my University using Google Map??

Please, I need your help as soon as possible.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where you able to solve your issue? If you were, please post an answer or contact me (you'll find information to reach me in my contact profile)

Answer (score 0):

Try to unblock regional internet restrictions in your mobile device

by using vpn application.
There are lots of applications for that purpose. try this one:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aed.droidvpn&hl=en

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I don't think this would help him, as it sounds like the regional restrictions are ones that would limit the applicable buildings to ones in those three regions.